# To use pause.until() in a python program

Tags: python, pause

I tried using the pause.until() program in a function to pause the program until a specific time but it always shows an error. Here is the code --:

```
def freeTime(end1,end2):
    print("Free time!!")
    notification.notify(
            title = "Enjoy sir as",
            message = "Itss free time!!",
            timeout = 5,
            )
    to_do_over = input("Are ur to-do's over sir?")
    to_do = 3
    if "yes" in to_do_over:
        to_do = True
        print("Good, let me do something for u to enjoy")
        dad()
        webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

    elif "no" in to_do_over:
        to_do = False
        print(f"Ok, will come back at {end1}: {end2} and then we will enjoy!!")
        me()
        webbrowser.open("https://classroom.google.com/a/not-turned-in/all")
        while to_do == False:
            print("")
            end_time = datetime.datetime(year, month, date, end1, end2)
            print(end_time)
            pause.until(end_time)
            dad()
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
            to_do = True
```

The error it shows is --:
end_time = datetime.datetime(year, month, date, 7, 30)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: The issue is not with pause.until, the issue is reported by Date time, one of the values you are passing must not be an int and must be a str

Comment: I wrote --:    freeTime(7,30) Is there some problem with that???

Comment: it could be any value passed to date time that might be a str not an int, have you checked what the values and types are for the variables year, month, date. Can you show how you define these in your code. Also you have used the variable date for passing the day to date time, where normally the naming convention for this would be day. Not sure if you have mixed up your variables here or you genuinely have the day stored in a variable called date.

Comment: now = datetime.datetime.now()
day = now.strftime("%A").lower()
date = now.strftime("%d")
hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
year = now.year
month = now.month      Should I put day there, instead of date???

Comment: there is your issue `date = now.strftime("%d")` this will return a str value to the variable named date, then you pass this as the day to date time, but datetime needs this to be an int. so you would need to convert it to an int.

Comment: do I need to make it `date = int(now.strftime("%d"))` Will it work then?

Comment: or just do it the same way you do for the mondth and year etc. `date = now.day` since date time object will return you the day as an int anyway

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thank you so muchh for your help,I've been stuggling with this piece of code for ages and came to know about stack overflow. It was a great help!!! TYSM sir.